# xlrd installation issue

Tags: python, import, installation, xlrd

I'm currently running python 2.7 on windows 7 64bit and am having difficulty trying to get xlrd to work.

After running any script with:

```
import xlrd
```

I get "ImportError: No module named xlrd"

Installing using the exe and msi from the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/ completes normally and I can see the xlrd folder and it's contents in the regular directory C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. But I still get the 'ImportError'. Then, I tried installing using the source folder. I opened up powershell and changed the directory to the source folder, then typed in:

```
python setup.py install
```

But in the middle of the process, I get the message:

```
...
creating C:\Program Files <x86>\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\xlrd
error: could not create 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PsychoPy2\Lib\site-packages\xlrd': Access is denied"
```

I'm assuming there is some kind of issue with the psychopy library I previously have installed. But is it a separate issue? And is there any other workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: nevermind, just uninstalled psychopy, pywin32, and xlrd, and then reinstalled xlrd using the msi installer!

Comment: Did this work? I'm having the same problem running Python on Linux.